# how do I create a new column out of a dictionary's sub string on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following repo for the files: https://github.com/Glarez/learning.git

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjO5h.png)

I need to create a column with the bold part of that string under the params column: "ufield_18":**"ONLY"** I dont see how can I get that since I'm learning to code from scratch. The solution to this would be nice, but what I would really appreciate is you to point me at the right direction to get the answer for myself. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want the exact answer. I will provide you one of the ways to achieve this:

1. filter the params column into a dictionary variable
2. create a loop to access the keys of the dictionary
3. append it to the pandas df you have (df[key] = np.nan) - Make sure you add some values while appending the column if your df already has some rows or just add np.nan

note np is numpy library which needs to be imported